# Get weekend timestamp in python

Tags: python, timestamp

I have to convert get weekend timestamp from php to python. I google many times but couldn't find the answer.
in php I can do

```
endOfWeek = strtotime('next saturday, 11:59:59pm America/Los_Angeles');
```

Do you guys know how to do the thing like that in python pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from datetime import *
from dateutil.tz import *
today = datetime.now(tzutc())
new_time = today+relativedelta(weekday=FR, hours=11, minutes=59, seconds=00)
new_time = new_time.astimezone(gettz("America/Los Angeles"))
print(new_time)
```

#### Output:

> 2016-09-02 02:19:21.899007-05:00

Answer (score 0):

@Jose
Yeah Thank you. I seen work in local for me. But we plan to use Python on Google App Engine and It not allow use extend library. But I find how to do it use standard date, time modules

> ```
>     year_no = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isocalendar(0)
>     week_no = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isocalendar()[1] + 1  # next week
>     next_monday_datetime = time.strptime(year_no + ' ' + week_no + ' ' + '1', '%Y %W %w')  # monday of next week date
>     # get 23:59:59 of previous sunday timestamp for back-ward compatible with old stack
>     end_of_week_refer = time.mktime(next_monday_datetime) - 1
> ```

Although I didn't change it to America/Los Angeles time zone yet, but it should be easy and I already get weekend timestamp